# Rudin's "Principles of Mathematical Analysis" Example 1.1

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis

This probably involves some very easy algebra, but I am stuck and would appreciate some help.  Walter Rudin's Example 1.1 on page 2 of Principles of Mathematical Analysis includes the following observation:

If $p > 0$ and $q = p - \dfrac{p^2 - 2}{p + 2} = \dfrac{2p + 2}{p + 2}$ then

If $p^2 - 2 > 0$ this implies $0 < q < p$.

I can see how $q < p$, but why is $q$ (necessarily) $> 0$?

I'm sure I am missing something obvious.

Comment: >I can see how q < p, but why is q necessarily > 0. Because $q = (2p+2)/(p+2)$ is the ratio of two positive numbers?

Comment: Look at how it is defined. And note that $p$ is as well.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141774/choice-of-q-in-baby-rudins-example-1-1 for an explanation of why this $q$ was chosen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because p is positive, so also $\,\displaystyle{q:=\frac{2p+2}{p+2}>0}$

Comment: Thanks, I knew it had to be something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Because from your argument we have,
$$\displaystyle q= p-\frac{p^{2}-2}{p+2}.$$
$$\displaystyle \therefore q=\frac{p(p+2)-(p^{2}-2)}{p+2}.$$
$$\displaystyle \Rightarrow q= \frac{2p+2}{p+2}>0.(\because p>0).$$

Comment: So basically, your explanation is that "the result follows from the hypotheses" ??